# Pandas split value in rows into multiple rows based on delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe in the below format.

```
[apple]
[banana]
[apple, orange]
```

I would like to convert this such that it has only unique values but it split by row for each value:

```
apple
banana
orange
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First [`unnest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51752361/9081267) your list to rows, then use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
# Make example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[['apple'], ['banana'], ['apple', 'orange']]})

              Col1
0          [apple]
1         [banana]
2  [apple, orange]
```

---

```
df = explode_list(df, 'Col1').drop_duplicates()
```

**Output**

```
     Col1
0   apple
1  banana
2  orange
```

---

Function used from linked answer

```
def explode_list(df, col):
    s = df[col]
    i = np.arange(len(s)).repeat(s.str.len())
    return df.iloc[i].assign(**{col: np.concatenate(s)})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to flatten list of lists and the [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to drop duplicates maintaining order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import itertools
```

---

```
df['col2']=OrderedDict.fromkeys(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df.col)).keys()
print(df)
```

---

```
               col    col2
0          [apple]   apple
1         [banana]  banana
2  [apple, orange]  orange
```

Comment: thank you for that but I am getting an error `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable` though the column we iterating is a column of dtype `object`

Comment: @scottmartin hmm. works for me for the sample. are you using this independently is are you integrating this line with some other code, you have to see why it fails. Not sure.